# How do I use a Consumer in a React app with TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a React Component defined as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import { AuthUserContext } from '../Session';

const Account = () => (
  <AuthUserContext.Consumer>
    {
      authUser => {
        return(
        <div>
          <h6 className="accountInfo"><strong>Account:</strong> {authUser.email} </h6>
        </div>
        )
      }
    }
  </AuthUserContext.Consumer>
);

export default Account;
```

This throws the error `Object is possibly 'null'` referring to the use of authUser.email in the line with h6.

Even if I do this:

```
authUser  ? <h6 className="accountInfo"><strong>Account:</strong>
              {authUser.email}
              </h6>
          : null
```

it still gives the same error.

When `authUser` is defined in `withAuthentication`, its value is initially set to null, but I thought that adding in the check for `authUser` would ensure that it was never null when it hit `authUser.email`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does email in your user type is optional?

Comment: If the authUser is set, then email must be set too.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the information from the comments, so it should match the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior could have been caused by missing braces around the conditional expression, but instead it was because of a combination of a `null` context type and an inaccurate TypeScript error.

If the context is created like this

```
const context: {email: string} | null = null
const AuthUserContext = React.createContext(context)
```

TypeScript will infer type `React.Context<null>`, because the type of `context` is narrowed to `null`. Normally this would just cause a missing property error on usage, but TypeScript appears to have an issue with error messages for `null` constants in conditonal expressions inside closures.

In the code below ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3&ssl=3&ssc=85&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBCMF4ZgK4Bs0ChSVgdwFMBLAJwBNEYAKASkQD44YB%20OAOgAcYAuGAcj4wA9EJgBREiRAleAeQBGAKwLBYRCDA4gIEIvLQBPfqgx822cNGQgoAdWLlK8ViE49%20gkeMnTeABSkOAhIoIz4OQTIQAg0wGxgCAA91WHAYUKDjAgA3YLNMIA)), `weird` yields an `Object is possibly 'null'` error on `o`, whereas `nonWeird` yields a proper error message.

```
const o = null
const weird = () => o ? o.p : '' // Error: Object is possibly 'null'.
const notWeird = o ? o.p : '' // Error: Property 'p' does not exist on type 'never'.
```

This explains the strange error message on `authUser.email`. The root problem can be fixed by providing a type parameter to `createContext`:

```
const React.createContext<{email: string} | null>(null)
```

Comment: Thanks, but your example is what I have - the braces are in there.

Comment: Hmm, what type do you see if you hover over `AuthUserContext` in the body of `Account`, is it `React.Context<null>`?

Comment: Yes, I get: const AuthUserContext: React.Context<null>

Comment: Ah great, then it gets a type that's too narrow because of the initialization with `null`. You can fix that by adding a parameter `createContext`, something like `React.createContext<{email: string} | null>(null)`.

Comment: That worked - thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Nice! Let me put the information in the answer.